# Save multiple array in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

My problem is I have 4 arrays, `a[1]=1, a[2]=3, a[3]=4, a[4]=5`, and want to save as new string/ char, so the output will be `s[ ]={1345}`

I try to define like this, but it doesn't works

```
char s[]= new char [5];
s={'a[1]','a[2]','a[3]','a[4]'};
```

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you're trying there. but you should know that 'a[1]' is not a valid char. try with: s = {'1', '2', '3' ,'4'};

Comment: if you remove the quotes around the a[], it would probably work

Comment: If my guess is right, you want the array variable values in `s`? Your code would be `s={a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]};` then, without quotes

Comment: You should loop over all the arrays, and build a string from the values.

Comment: "I have 4 arrays, a[1]=1, a[2]=3, a[3]=4, a[4]=5" - that is a single array, with 4 values in it. Just to make things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of initialising the char array `s[]` and then setting the value in the next line, you can directly initialize the array like: `char s[] = {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]};`

Answer (score 0):

In Java the concept of String is fairly simple. You dont have to define it as a character array. Just take a String variable and concat the array values to it. The below is how you can do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
String output = a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3];
System.out.println(output);
}
```

Hope it shall work for you.

Comment: shouldn't it be `int[] a` or `int a[]`?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for pointing out.